# EF7, what is wrong with my relation here?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

The relation seams to be find and works with other example but when trying to get with all of the possible Include it fails with the error.

```
 Widget widget = _dbContext.Widgets.Where(w => w.Id == id)
            .Include(w => w.DataSource)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.DataSourceParamProc)
                       .ThenInclude(s => s.DataSourceParamProcParams)
            .Include(w => w.DataSource)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.SelectOptions)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

POCO's:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DataSourceId { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
}

public class DataSource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StoredProc { get; set; }
    public string DataBaseName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DataSourceParam> DataSourceParams { get; set; }
}

public class DataSourceParam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DataSourceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSourceParamProc DataSourceParamProc { get; set; }
}

public class DataSourceParamProc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StoredProc { get; set; }
    public string DataBaseName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DataSourceParam")]
    public int DataSourceParamId { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSourceParam DataSourceParam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DataSourceParamProcParam> DataSourceParamProcParams { get; set; }
}

public class DataSourceParamProcParam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public int DataSourceParamProcId { get; set; }
}

public class SelectOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public int DataSourceParamId { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSourceParam DataSourceParam { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting error :

> A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.

If I comment this line it works:

```
Widget widget = _dbContext.Widgets.Where(w => w.Id == id)
            .Include(w => w.DataSource)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.DataSourceParamProc)
                       //.ThenInclude(s => s.DataSourceParamProcParams)
            .Include(w => w.DataSource)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.SelectOptions)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or If I comment this one it works as well:

```
Widget widget = _dbContext.Widgets.Where(w => w.Id == id)
            .Include(w => w.DataSource)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.DataSourceParamProc)
                       .ThenInclude(s => s.DataSourceParamProcParams)
            //.Include(w => w.DataSource)
            //    .ThenInclude(d => d.DataSourceParams)
            //        .ThenInclude(p => p.SelectOptions)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

If I separate this it works as well:

```
       Widget widget = _dbContext.Widgets.Where(w => w.Id == id)
            .Include(w => w.ChartAttributes)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.ChartAttributeType)  
            .Include(w => w.WidgetCategory)
            .Include(w => w.WidgetSeries)
            .Include(w => w.WidgetType)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        DataSource ds = _dbContext.DataSources.Where(d => d.Id == widget.DataSourceId)
                .Include(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.SelectOptions)
                .Include(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.DataSourceParamProc)
                       .ThenInclude(s => s.DataSourceParamProcParams).FirstOrDefault();

        widget.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: Maybe its just me, but I can't see `SelectOptions` anywhere in the POCO (and I'm not yet working with EF7, so i dunno if its a special thing.

Comment: No, you are correct I have missed this one. Just added.